# Jprofiler integrated with TestNG under eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, testng, jprofiler

JProfiler does not give me any 'Profile As' with TestNG as it does with JUNit.
Is TestNG integrated with eclipse ?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not available and will be added in JProfiler 10.1.

Comment: any release date for 10.1 ?

Comment: I have 10.1.1. No TestNg feature :-(

Comment: Indeed, we had to postpone it. Currently scheduled for 11.0, I hope it makes it, otherwise it will definitely be in 11.1.